# SharePoint Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages "Access is Denied"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I get the following error when I access any admin feature in SharePoint 2007 such as "Site Settings" or "Create Page."  When I restart the server, the error is temporarily fixed but it comes back again in relatively short time.

I've checked other questions related to this post and none of them have the answer.  I assume it's security related but then why is it fixed temporarily when the server is restarted?

**Update:** I just restarted IIS and the issue is temporarily resolved again... so confusing.  Man, I can feel this question getting the `tumbleweed` badge soon.

> `Could not load file or assembly
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is
>   denied. at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, Assembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean throwOnFail) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.AddAssemblyDependency(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean
>   addDependentAssemblies) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String
>   directiveName, IDictionary directive)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String
>   text, Encoding fileEncoding)`

Comment: I've updated my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607407/access-denied-on-microsoft-sharepoint-applicationpages) with the lastest information I have. I hope it can put you on the right track. :)

Comment: You can also look here : http://sladescross.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sharepoint-applicationpages-version12-0-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken71e9bce111e9429c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in contact recently with someone that had the same problem. He opened a case with Microsoft and they suggested to put a copy of Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll in the GAC. It may not be the best solution, but it fixes the issues.

Comment: Welcome to 2k rep @Tom. Gave you a bounty for this.  Errr in 23 hrs I can award it.